# How can I create an array of objects based on some of another array object's properties?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This this data:

```
const cocktail = [
    {
        "idDrink":"13070",
        "strDrink":"Fahrenheit 5000",
        "strGlass":"Shot glass",
        "strInstructions":"Cover bottom of shot gla",
        "strIngredient1":"Firewater",
        "strIngredient2":"Absolut Peppar",
        "strIngredient3":"Tabasco sauce",
        "strIngredient4":null,
        "strMeasure1":"1/2 oz ",
        "strMeasure2":"1/2 oz ",
        "strMeasure3":"1 dash ",
        "strMeasure4":null
    }
]
```

it's my hope to return an array of objects that populate the non-`null` values of each **strMeasure[n]** and **strIngredient[n]**:

```
[
    {
        strMeasure1: value,
        strIngredient1: value
    },
    {
        strMeasure2: value,
        strIngredient2: value
    },
    …
]
```

from `cocktail` array above, the ideal output would be:

```
[
    {
        measure: '1/2 oz',
        name: 'Firewater'
    },
    {
        measure: '1/2 oz',
        name: 'Absolut Peppar'
    },
    {
        measure: '1 dash',
        name: 'Tobasco sauce'
    },
]
```

Comment: is cocktail always an array of length 1?

Comment: yes, it will be

Comment: How do i know which Ingredient will go with which measure

Comment: by the number at the end of each respective key in the source data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

Use:

- `Object.entries(cocktail[0])` to get an array of [key, value] from the data
- `filter` to get the Ingredients and Measures - and ignore the ones with `null` values
- `reduce` to build up the resulting array

Like this:

```js
const cocktail = [
    {
        "idDrink":"13070",
        "strDrink":"Fahrenheit 5000",
        "strGlass":"Shot glass",
        "strInstructions":"Cover bottom of shot gla",
        "strIngredient1":"Firewater",
        "strIngredient2":"Absolut Peppar",
        "strIngredient3":"Tabasco sauce",
        "strIngredient4":null,
        "strMeasure1":"1/2 oz ",
        "strMeasure2":"1/2 oz ",
        "strMeasure3":"1 dash ",
        "strMeasure4":null
    }
]
const result = Object.entries(cocktail[0])
.filter(([k,v])=>v && k.match(/^str(Ingredient|Measure)\d+$/))
.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    const [t, n] = k.match(/^str(Ingredient|Measure)(\d+)$/).slice(1);
    acc[n-1] = {...acc[n-1], [t]:v};
    return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result);
```

You could also do it without the filter step

```
const result = Object.entries(cocktail[0])
.reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    if (v) {
        const [t, n] = k.match(/^str(Ingredient|Measure)(\d+)$/)?.slice(1) ?? [] ;
        acc[n-1] = {...acc[n-1], [t]:v};
    }
    return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you, Jaromanda X!!!

Comment: I've added an alternative, for some reason I can make it into a snippet - but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could benefit from using javascripts map() method for parsing out the specific key value pairs from within the object in the array.
There are also several ways you could extract the values you want from inside the object such as through dot notation. I have attached a few links here that are  very helpful and will give you a much deeper and basic understanding of how to achieve this.

[From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-convert-array-of-objects-to-array-of-values

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-of-objects-tutorial-how-to-create-update-and-loop-through-objects-using-js-array-methods/

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an array of object which will have `measure` and `id`. Then use the `id` to get the value from cocktail array

```js
const cocktail = [{
  "idDrink": "13070",
  "strDrink": "Fahrenheit 5000",
  "strGlass": "Shot glass",
  "strInstructions": "Cover bottom of shot gla",
  "strIngredient1": "Firewater",
  "strIngredient2": "Absolut Peppar",
  "strIngredient3": "Tabasco sauce",
  "strIngredient4": null,
  "strMeasure1": "1/2 oz ",
  "strMeasure2": "1/2 oz ",
  "strMeasure3": "1 dash ",
  "strMeasure4": null
}]
const obj = [];
for (let keys in cocktail[0]) {

  if (keys.includes('strIngredient')) {
    const tempObj = {
      measure: cocktail[0][keys],
      id: keys.charAt(keys.length - 1)
    }
    obj.push(tempObj)
  }
}
obj.forEach((elem) => elem.value = cocktail[0][`strMeasure${elem.id}`])
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lodash** if you don't mind

```js
const cocktail = {"idDrink":"13070","strDrink":"Fahrenheit 5000","strGlass":"Shot glass","strInstructions":"Cover bottom of shot gla","strIngredient1":"Firewater","strIngredient2":"Absolut Peppar","strIngredient3":"Tabasco sauce","strIngredient4":null,"strMeasure1":"1/2 oz ","strMeasure2":"1/2 oz ","strMeasure3":"1 dash ","strMeasure4":null};
    
const parseKey = (str) => [...str.matchAll(/(strIngredient|strMeasure)(\d+)/g)].flat();
  
const maping = { strIngredient: 'name', strMeasure: 'measure' };

const iter = (acc, value, key) => {
    const [,  keyName, keyNumber] = parseKey(key);
    if (value && keyName) {
      acc[keyNumber] ??= {};
      acc[keyNumber][maping[keyName]] = value;
    }
    return acc;
};

const result = _(cocktail).transform(iter, {}).values();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```